# What is the best way to view SQL queries to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

My GUI makes some queries to a PostgreSQL database. I want to know what these queries are. How can I change the settings for PostgreSQL so I can view what specific queries are executed when I do things in the GUI?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT -->> set log_statement = all; kill -HUP server_pid; tail -f logfile;

Comment: @joop: `pg_ctl reload` might be a bit cleaner then using `kill`